# store image name into database from directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have multiple directories in my application which contains images. I want to store the image names of all the images into a database. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

My directory names are in a pattern like below :

1. dir1 ----- contains images
2. dir2 ----- contains images
3. dir3 ----- contains images
4. dir4 ----- contains images
5. dir5 ----- contains images 
   .
   .
   .
   .
6. dir99 ----- contains images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the files are jpg, and you have a connection to sql, and a table that have one column name, this will save all the directory+imagename
If you want only the image name, change command.Parameters.Add("@name",dir+file.Name); to command.Parameters.Add("@name",file.Name);

Define a list of string

```
List<string>directories= yourlistofdirectories.

    foreach(dir in directories)
  {

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(dir);//Assuming Test is your Folder
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg"); //Getting image files
        foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
        {
          String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Name (name) VALUES(@name)";
          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db.Connection);
          command.Parameters.Add("@name",dir+file.Name);
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to pass list of directories???

Comment: List<string> directories = new List<string>(new string[] { "c:/dir1", "c:/dir2", "c:/dir3" });